# Shiny input variables are selectively ignored by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want my shiny app to be able to plot data frames with a varying number of columns. Since I don't expect the data to contain more than 5 columns, I wrote an explicit list of all possible cases for the ggplot object. I also want the size of the first object to be variable using a slider on the UI.

The problem is that the value of that slider is only recognized for data with more than one column.

To test this here is example data with one data column: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/182Qi-2I37OscSeLir_AyXdoedstIxx6D/view?usp=sharing

And here with two:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eB0eKvgfj94xIp80P0SG3QnoGZJ1Zq9a/view?usp=sharing

This is my first question here and I'm not to sure how to ideally provide examples for shiny apps using a fileInput. Please let me know if there is a better way than this.

```
#The ui

shinyUI(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel(""),

    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Choose an Excel (.xlsx) File", 
                multiple = FALSE, 
                accept = c("text/xlsx", "text/microsoft-excel-pen-XML-format-spreadsheet-file", ".xlsx"),
                width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Find...",
                placeholder = "No File selected"
      ),

      sliderInput(inputId = "width", label = "width", min = 0.01, max = 0.4, value = 0.2, step = 0.01)),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("graph"), height = "600px", quoted = TRUE)
  )
)
```

```
#and the server

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
            data.frame(read_xlsx(input$file$datapath))
           })


  output$graph <- renderPlot({

      print(

        #somehow the interactive heigth setting is now muted within the expression
        ggplot(data(), aes(x = data()[,1], y = "", fill = as.factor(data()[2:ncol(data())])) ) +
        {if(ncol(data()) >= 2)geom_tile(aes(x = data()[,1], y = 0, fill = as.factor(data()[,2])), data(), width = 0.2, height = input$width, size = 2)} + 
        {if(ncol(data()) >= 3)geom_tile(aes(x = data()[,1], y = 0.125, fill = as.factor(data()[,3])), data(), width = 0.2, height = 0.02, size = 2)} +
        {if(ncol(data()) >= 4)geom_tile(aes(x = data()[,1], y = -0.125, fill = as.factor(data()[,4])), data(), width = 0.2, height = 0.02, size = 2)} +
        {if(ncol(data()) == 5)geom_tile(aes(x = data()[,1], y = -0.145, fill = as.factor(data()[,5])), data(), width = 0.2, height = 0.02, size = 2)}

          scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL, labels = NULL)
          )



  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found the error. The problem is that `scale_y_continuous`automatically rescales the y-axis to the size of the plot elements. In my case, this didn't show up if I added fixed-size plot elements (as is done by the program, if the data contains more than one column) that also set limits to the size of the y-axis. The solution in this particular case for me was to use `ylim(-0.2005, 0.2005)`instead, hence fixing y-axis size.

Answer (score 0):

The `renderPlot({...})` is already reactive. You can drop `PLOT <-reactive({` and `print(` and just go right into the `ggplot()`

Overall, I think I'd do something like this:

```r
output$graph <- renderPlot({

  df <- data()
  names(df) <- paste0("v", 1:length(df))


  # initial plot
  p <- 
    ggplot(df, aes(x = v1)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL, labels = NULL)


  # conditions
  if (ncol(df) >= 2) { 
    p <- p + geom_tile(aes(y = 0, fill = as.factor(v2), width = 0.2, height = input$width, size = 2)
  }


  if (ncol(df) >= 3) { 
    p <- p + geom_tile(aes(y = 0.125, fill = as.factor(v3), width = 0.2, height = 0.02, size = 2)
  }


  etc...

  # return
  p

})
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up! It doesn't change the behaviour of the if-statements, though

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end it was even more simple. I added my solution.